# Build scatter-gather in akka

Tags: scala, akka

I want to build actor chain with scatter-gather pattern

My flow looks like this:

```
a1=>a2=>a3=>a4=>a5
```

When I creating actors I use following code:

```
val a5: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new A5))
val a4: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new A4(a5, otherArgs4))
val a3: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new A3(a4, otherArgs3)))
val a2: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new A2(a3)))
val a1: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new A1(a2)))
```

Can I create actors chain in smarter and more configurable way?

Comment: What is the use case for linking your actors together like that?

Comment: I want to have a group of actors processing the same event. Every actor is adding something to message (I'm passing the same message class between actors). We can assume that A1 is listing files on network resource, A2 is processing response and scheduling downloading resources on A3 (A3 can be load balanced using RoundRobin). A4 is aggregating responses and passes result to A5.

Comment: This is inspired on example from "Akka in action".